# How to use C code generated by Matlab?

Tags: c, matlab, dev-c++, matlab-coder

I used the Matlab Coder to produce C code for a simple Matlab Array adding function which adds the elements of two arrays. Once done, the Matlab Coder gives me a package containing .c and header files ( which also includes a C file of the function itself ).

1. How do I use these C files in for e.g. programs like Dev C++ or Code::Blocks ?
2. How do I initialize emxArray_real_T variables to incorporate elements of an integer array ?

Comment: Are they C++ functions or C language functions?  (C++ language functions can be overridden and overloaded, C doesn't have this capability.)

Comment: I did that last week. Juste create an empty project from your IDE, import all the files (including the main example), compile and run. That's it!

Comment: The files are C files. I do have Dev-C++ but whenever I try to compile the main file ( which is given by Matlab itself ), it gives me linker errors saying : " undefined reference to `emxCreateND_real_T' " or " undefined reference to `emxInitArray_real_T' "

Comment: Also, when I make a new Empty Project, import all the files including the main example files, I get an error saying "mingw32-make.exe: *** No rule to make target 'Untitled3.o', needed by 'Project2.exe'.  Stop."

Comment: C is not C++ is not C!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an IDE that supports c, like Dev C++ or Code Blocks, you just need to open the file with that IDE, compile and run it. For Code Blocks, press F9 to compile and run your code.

Edit: The `undefined reference to emxInitArray_real_T` error is due to an linking error. You can make your costumized MakeFile and select it in (for CodeBlocks: Project->properties->Project setting). Try this one:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=  -g
OBJECTS= main.o
LIBS = -Llibs -lMat

# --- targets
all:    main
main:   $(OBJECTS)
        $(CC)  -o main $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS)

main.o: main.cpp
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -Ilibs -c main.cpp
```

Edit 2: For Dev C++:

1 - Create a new project using File >> New Project. You can ignore the C/C++ options if you use a custom makefile. Also, an empty project will do.

2 - Add the source and header files to the new project using Project >> Add to Project or the '+' sign in the middle of the top toolbar.

3 - Go to Project >> Project Options (Alt+P) >> Makefile and tick the 'Use custom makefile' option. Then point Dev-C++ to the custom makefile below.

, as pointed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13544684/running-a-project-in-dev-c).

Comment: I do have Dev-C++ but whenever I try to compile the main file ( which is given by Matlab itself ), it gives me linker errors saying : " undefined reference to `emxCreateND_real_T' " or " undefined reference to `emxInitArray_real_T' "

Comment: Thanks. It says "Successfully generated all binary outputs" .... But I just have one more question. If I want to call the compiled function ( say it's declaration is Func1(int x, int y) ), how do I call it now in a new C file ?